# How to sort result based on matching

Tags: mysql, search

I have this problem with [this site](http://mystockalarm.com) where user can search by stock symbol or stock name

If it matchs exact with a symbol, results need to be displayed first then the remaining.

Table structure is like this : `pk | symbol | stockname`

**Example of  scenario :**
`symbol = eta`
`stock name = energy transfer equity`

This result with exact match with `ete` but it got buried in search results.

Could you help me solving this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use e.g.

```
select symbol, stockname
from yourtable
where ...
order by (symbol = 'eta') desc
```

`(symbol = 'eta')` will have the value 1 when it matches, 0 if it doesn't match.